# AngularJS: calculating position with an expression breaks in IE

Tags: angularjs

I want to calculate the position of elements based on the state. So this is what I came up with:

```
<div ng-repeat="room in rooms | toArray | orderBy:'id'" 
    style="right:{{getRightOffset($index + 1)}}px">
    // ...
</div>
```

getRightOffset is a function that calculates the right position. It works great in chrome & firefox, but not in IE10 (haven't tried others yet). In IE10 all these divs just have a right position of 0. Confirmed the function doesn't get called at all.

UPDATE: Here is an example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dxTa5/2/ . try to run it in IE 10 and the function is not called. In chrome it works.

Comment: doesn't do much good showing a call to a function that doesn't work without showing the code in the function

Comment: @charlietfl what's the difference what the function is when i'm telling you it's not being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [ngStyle](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle) instead of `style=`.  If you're using inline expressions, you're better in most cases to use the `ng-` prefixed version since the browser doesn't attempt to interpret them.